# Service unable to start activity of other app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an application "x" that starts a service(in some other package) on button click. This service should now read call logs and send data to application "y" which should write the data in sd card. Presently, my service runs on button click but the application "y" doesn't as I have a toast in application "y" and it never comes up. The permissions are given in for reading logs and since am using custom action the same is included in intent filter of application "y". Can someone tell the reason for this problem.

service code

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Service started.");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
  /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return 0;
        }
        Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, strOrder);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append("Call Log :");
        int h = 0;
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext() && h != 20) {
            String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String callType = null;
            h++;
            int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
            switch (callcode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Outgoing";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Incoming";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    callType = "Missed";
                    break;
            }
            sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNum + " \nCall Type:--- "
                    + callType + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDate
                    + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
            sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
        }
        managedCursor.close();
       managedCursor.close();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    String CUSTOM_ACTION = "com.example.sonali.callreadingservice.CALL_LOGS";
    sendIntent.setAction(CUSTOM_ACTION);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (Serializable) sb);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
    this.stopSelf();
    return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("slog", "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

application "y" main activity

```
``public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_call);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        handleSendText(intent);

        }


    void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        try {
            if (sharedText != null) {
                textView.setText(sharedText);
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sdCard);
// Writes the content to the file
                writer.write(sharedText);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

intent-filter of application "y"
`

```
`<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.sonali.callreadingservice.CALL_LOGS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: did you defined the activity you want to run from the app Y inside the manifest of the service ?!!

Comment: what do you need that service for? just to send `Cursor`'s data? why not to use a `ContentProvider`?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat no I didn't. Can you tell me how to write it?

Comment: I will try by ContentProvider. I have a doubt. All that I am writing in onstartcommand funtion of service is it ever executing?Should I use super.onStartCommand or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your custom action in the Manifest to the Activity.

```
    <activity 
        android:name="MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.sonali.callreadingservice.CALL_LOGS"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: You also need to add a default category for the intent-filter.
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: There are 2 intent filter and in both I have added <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: @mine0901 No, not LAUNCHER. You need to add CATEGORY=DEFAULT, otherwise the `Activity` will not be found during Intent-resolution.

Comment: Made the changes. No difference!!